# chain of compact subspaces must be nonempty

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a compact space and suppose $\{ F_i \} $ is a collection of closed subsets of $X$ such that $F_{i+1} \subseteq F_i $ for all $i$. , then we must have $\bigcap_i F_i \neq \varnothing $.

MY try: Suppose $\bigcap_i F_i  = \varnothing $. We know the $\{ F_i \} $ must all be compact since they are closed sets living inside a compact space. Notice the collection $\mathcal{O} = \{ X \setminus F_i \} $ is definitely an open cover for $X$. Since $X$ is compact, $\mathcal{O} $ must have an finite open subcollection that covers $X$. How can I use my hypothesis that $F_{i+1} \subseteq F_i$ to get a contradiction. thanks.

Comment: I guess all the $F_i$ should be nonempty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You went astray when you said that $\mathcal{O}$ is definitely an open cover of $X$. It’s definitely a family of open subsets of $X$, but it doesn’t necessarily cover $X$.

- Show that $\mathcal{O}$ covers $X$ if and only if $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n=\varnothing$.

Now use that to get your contradiction: if $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n=\varnothing$, then *something*, and hence *contradiction*.

Comment: Brian: $\bigcup O = \bigcup ( X \setminus F_i ) = X \setminus \bigcap F_i = X $ is this correct ?

Comment: @DonAnselmo: That’s a proof that if $\bigcap_nF_n=\varnothing$, then $\bigcup\mathcal{O}=X$. The converse is equally easy: if $\bigcup\mathcal{O}=X$, then $$\bigcap_nF_n=\bigcap_n(X\setminus F_n)=X\setminus\bigcup\mathcal{O}=\varnothing\;.$$

Comment: So, if $\bigcap F_i = \varnothing$, then $\mathcal{O}$ covers $X$.  How can we get contradiction from here?

Comment: @DonAnselmo: $X$ is compact, so $\mathcal{O}$ has a finite subcover, say $\{O_{n_1},\ldots,O_{n_k}\}$ for some finite set $\{n_1,\ldots,n_k\}$, where $O_m=X\setminus F_m$ for each $m\in\Bbb N$. What can you say about $F_{n_1}\cap\ldots\cap F_{n_k}$?

Comment: i mean the intersection must be empty

Comment: @DonAnselmo: Exactly — and there’s your contradiction.

Comment: Brian, but we havent used the fact that $F_{i+1} \subseteq F_i $

Comment: @DonAnselmo: You use that to get your contradiction. If $n_1<\ldots<n_k$, the fact that the sets are nested means that $F_{n_1}\cap\ldots\cap F_{n_k}=F_{n_k}$. (Note: Your problem should include a hypothesis that the sets $F_i$ are non-empty.)

Comment: Got it! thanks very much Brian !! You are the topology genius of MSE!!

Comment: @DonAnselmo: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

In fact something stronger exists. $X$ is compact iff for every family of sets {$F_{i}:i\in I$},$F_{i}$ closed subsets of $X$ that have the finite intersection property we have that $\cap${$ F_{i}:i\in I$}$\neq \emptyset$(the proof of this one is easy enough,but i don't write it because it needs many symbols.If you want it though i'll be happy to write it down:)). Here if we choose finite number of $F_{i}$ we have that their intersection is non-empty and because $X$ is compact we have the result